# generic function to test if objects in enumeration contain a property, and if it is equal to 10

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

In my test cases, I want to loop through a collection of objects (different objects, depending on the scenerio), and if the objects in the collection contain the property `location_id` I want to verify the id has a value of e.g. `10`

All the objects in the collection will be of the same type, but not all collections will have the same type i.e. some may be a collection of users, or a collection or articles etc.

I need this for my rspec tests.

Comment: BTW, you have asked almost 500 questions that you didn't accept an answer to. You should seriously consider voting up helpful answers and especially marking as accepted the one answer (if any) that best solved your problem. It helps the site, it helps other users with similar questions, and it helps you not get ignored. :)

Comment: @Phrogz: Thanks for saying it, and saying it in a civil manner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that by "contain a property" means "responds to a getter method":

```
def test_for_value( collection, getter_method, value )
  # Only look deeper if the collection isn't empty
  # and the first element has the method
  if (o=collection.first) && o.respond_to?( getter_method )
    collection.find{ |o| o.send(getter_method)==value }
  end
end

Person = Struct.new( :name, :age )

people = []
p test_for_value( people, :age, 38 )
#=> nil

people << Person.new( "Gavin", 38 )
people << Person.new( "Imogen", 5 )

p test_for_value( people, :age, 38 )
#=> #<struct Person name="Gavin", age=38>

p test_for_value( people, :age, 5 )
#=> #<struct Person name="Imogen", age=5>

p test_for_value( people, :horns, true )
#=> nil
```

If instead you are talking about collections of hashes and you want to lookup the hash key:

```
def test_for_value( collection, key, value )
  if (o=collection.first) && o.key?( key )
    collection.find{ |o| o[key]==value }
  end
end
```

Comment: wow, short and sweet, thanks! Now I want to report an error if the method exists, and the value != value, so I would use col.find in my case right?

Comment: You could have the method return `false` if the method doesn't exist, `nil` if the method exists but `Enumerable#find` returns `nil`, or the value if the method exists and equals the value. Not sure what you want when the collection is empty. `def find_it(col,m,v); ((o=col.first) && o.respond_to?(m)) ? col.find{ |o| o.send(m)==v } : false; end` With this you can explicitly test the return value for `false` versus `nil` to report an error or not.

Comment: I just want, if the objects contain the property getter_method, then ALL rows must have the value of 'value'.

Comment: @Blankman Oh, then you want [`Enumerable.all?`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Enumerable.html#M001499)